# React - onChange children component

Tags: function, reactjs, components, containers, children

I'm trying to figure out why onChange wont work on a children component, i have a component named `AlertMethod` and im calling from a container.

```
<AlertMethod
  onChange={this.methodSelected}
  label="Sms"
  value="sms"
/>
```

and `methodSelected` it's just a `console.log()` to test if getting called

```
methodSelected = (event, data) => {
  console.log(data);        
};
```

here's an img to explain it better.

[image]

so finally that function it wont getting called. that's my problem.

> EDIT

On my Container `AlertSystem.js` i want to update a state if a checkbox it's checked or not, so my checkbox component it's `Checkbox.js` it's a stateless function, it recive 2 props `label` and `value` nothing special. so in my container when my `Checkbox` Component CHANGED, update my state, so that's why i have a `onChange={this.methodSelected}` on the children component, because in the `methodSelected` function ill update my state with this.setState and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling `props.onClick` in AlertMethod

Answer (score 0):

Your child component `AlertMethod` is being passed the `onSubmit` prop but not using it.

Should look more like this:

```
export const AlertMethod = ({ label, value, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Checkbox value={value} fluid label={label} onClick={onClick} />
        </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: But i dont want to pass a prop to my children, i want to know in my container when changes my children, i dont know if i explain myself.

Comment: Share more code with us, I think everyone is assuming that you are trying to call this method when your child is clicked. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: edited, now you can see what i need to do, i cant show more code because it's simple as that lol.

Comment: Given your edit, my solution should still work. As of right now, your event is not actually attached to anything at all. It's simply being passed down, and needs to be hooked up to an html element. You're clicking, but nobody is listening! What my code will do is pass it up to the container to say "hey, container, I've been clicked, you do what you need to do from here", and it will handle the event in your `AlertSystem.js` container.

Comment: Im interesteted in this also But I have class that outputs text and selectbox but I wanna pass onchange event to master function that uses select class childrens onChange handler...